# Running a command on all kubernetes pods of a service

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Hey I'm running a kubernetes cluster and I want to run a command on all pods that belong to a specific service.

As far as I know kubectl exec can only run on a pod and tracking all my pods is a ridiculous amount of work (which is one of the benefits of services).

Is there any way or tool that gives you the ability to "broadcast" to all pods in a service?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have a look at DaemonSet in kubernetes, if it suits your requirements.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way using kubectl.  Although you can use a combination of kubectl get pods -l and then pipe to kubectl exec.  I saw some gist that wraps this in a shell. https://gist.github.com/mnadel/4ddcc0ba07d398b35dad89b4dfdc8308

Comment: @BalChua you should write that as an Answer, rather than a comment, because it is exactly correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Bal Chua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9476882/bal-chua) wrote, kubectl has no way to do this, but you can use bash script to do this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

PROGNAME=$(basename $0)

function usage {
    echo "usage: $PROGNAME [-n NAMESPACE] [-m MAX-PODS] -s SERVICE -- COMMAND"
    echo "  -s SERVICE   K8s service, i.e. a pod selector (required)"
    echo "     COMMAND   Command to execute on the pods"
    echo "  -n NAMESPACE K8s namespace (optional)"
    echo "  -m MAX-PODS  Max number of pods to run on (optional; default=all)"
    echo "  -q           Quiet mode"
    echo "  -d           Dry run (don't actually exec)"
}

function header {
    if [ -z $QUIET ]; then
        >&2 echo "###"
        >&2 echo "### $PROGNAME $*"
        >&2 echo "###"
    fi
}

while getopts :n:s:m:qd opt; do
    case $opt in
        d)
            DRYRUN=true
            ;;
        q)
            QUIET=true
            ;;
        m)
            MAX_PODS=$OPTARG
            ;;
        n)
            NAMESPACE="-n $OPTARG"
            ;;
        s)
            SERVICE=$OPTARG
            ;;
        \?)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z $SERVICE ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)

while test "$#" -gt 0; do
    if [ "$REST" == "" ]; then
        REST="$1"
    else
        REST="$REST $1"
    fi

    shift
done

if [ "$REST" == "" ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

PODS=()

for pod in $(kubectl $NAMESPACE get pods --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}); do
    echo $pod | grep -qe "^$SERVICE" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        PODS+=($pod)
    fi
done

if [ ${#PODS[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "service not found in ${NAMESPACE:-default}: $SERVICE"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -z $MAX_PODS ]; then
    PODS=("${PODS[@]:0:$MAX_PODS}")
fi

header "{pods: ${#PODS[@]}, command: \"$REST\"}"

for i in "${!PODS[@]}"; do
    pod=${PODS[$i]}
    header "{pod: \"$(($i + 1))/${#PODS[@]}\", name: \"$pod\"}"

    if [ "$DRYRUN" != "true" ]; then
        kubectl $NAMESPACE exec $pod -- $REST
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 22):

Here's a simple example with kubectl pipe to xargs, printing env of each pod:

```
k get pod \
    -l {your label selectors} \
    --field-selector=status.phase=Running \
    -o custom-columns=name:metadata.name --no-headers \
    | xargs -I{} kubectl exec {} env
```

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
kubectl -n alex get pods -l app=alex-admin-api -o name | xargs -I{} kubectl -n alex exec {} -- cat alexAdminApi.log >> alex-admin-api_pods.logs
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a simple kubectl plugin that "boardcast"s commands to all pods, using Tmux. Assuming that all your pods in the service should share the same labels in their spec, `app=foobar` for instance, you can use the command below,

```sh
kubectl tmux-exec -l app=foobar bash
```

The plugin is available on Github: [predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec](https://github.com/predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec). Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

there is also a kubectl plugin called `kubectl-exec-all` https://github.com/jpdasma/kubectl-exec-all that is doing a good job.
Can't work with krew index but you can save the content of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpdasma/kubectl-exec-all/master/unix/exec-all.sh to `/usr/local/bin/kubectl-exec_all` and don't forget to make it executable by running

```sh
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl-exec_all
```

then it work like this:

```sh
kubectl plugin exec-all daemonset docker-daemon -- docker system prune -a -f
```

Comment: This seems a little outdated. The readme says it supports kubectl 1.12. Does this work in supported versions?

Comment: For me it's working with the last kubectl version: 1.19

Answer (score 0):

How I did this. Hope it helps.

#Run this command and see what your pods names are

```
kubectl get pods -no-headers -n [YOUR_NAMESPACE]
```

#Get all pods with a specific word in their name.

#looking for a word (metx) in a file in each pod. Brings back the line that contains this word.

```
for _POD in $( kubectl get pods -no-headers -n [YOUR_NAMESPACE] | awk '{ print $1}' | grep [SOMETHING_TO_MATCH_ON_NAME_COLUMN] ); do 
  echo "${_POD}: $( kubectl exec -it ${_POD} -- cat /tmp/temp.log | grep -H metx "
done
```

Comment: is it maybe `--no-headers`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiexec Plugin `kubectl-multiexec`

```
$ cat kubectl-multiexec


#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "kubectl multiexec <pattern> command"
    exit 1
}

[ $# -lt 2 ] && usage

pattern=$1
shift 1
command="$@"
while IFS=/ read -r _ pod; do
    (
        kubectl exec $pod -- /bin/bash -c "$command" 2>&1 |
            awk -v pod=$pod '
                { 
                    printf "[%s]: \t %s\n", pod, $0
                }
            '
    ) &
done < <(kubectl get pods --no-headers -o name | grep $pattern)
wait
```

copy `kubectl-multiexec` to PATH

```
$ cp kubectl-multiexec ~/bin/
```

Usage:

```
$ kubectl multiexec foo free -h
```

````
[foo-docs-2-bq8pm]:          Mem:           236Gi        19Gi       194Gi        67Mi        23Gi       216Gi
[foo-docs-2-bq8pm]:          Swap:             0B          0B          0B
[foo-swagger-4-tmhhh]:                      total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
[foo-swagger-4-tmhhh]:       Mem:           236Gi        21Gi       203Gi        63Mi        13Gi       214Gi
[foo-swagger-4-tmhhh]:       Swap:             0B          0B          0B
[foo-sandbox-1-f8gsz]:                      total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
[foo-sandbox-1-f8gsz]:       Mem:           236Gi        18Gi       208Gi        63Mi        10Gi       217Gi
[foo-sandbox-1-f8gsz]:       Swap:             0B          0B          0B
[foo-overview-1-kzfmd]:                     total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
[foo-overview-1-kzfmd]:      Mem:           157Gi       8,5Gi       140Gi        61Mi       9,2Gi       148Gi
[foo-overview-1-kzfmd]:      Swap:             0B          0B          0B
[foo-rest-3-4tmzm]:                         total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
[foo-rest-3-4tmzm]:          Mem:           157Gi        41Gi        97Gi       232Mi        19Gi       115Gi
[foo-rest-3-4tmzm]:          Swap:             0B          0B          0B```
````