# Kubernetes : List all Container's OS Name and version (OS distro)

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes

I wanted to generate a list or table with the given information for all containers running on the given Kubernetes cluster:

1. Container's Image Name
2. Contianer's OS Name
3. Container's OS Version

The purpose is to get an inventory of all OS distro is being used in workload.

Comment: This isn't information that Kubernetes "knows" about your containers. Your only option would be to `kubectl exec` something inside the container that can get the information you want...and at that point, it's no longer a kubernetes question. It's just "how do I tell what distribution I'm running?", and a cursory search should reveal a variety of resources to help with that question.

Comment: You will have to write a custom script for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @larsks & @CodeWizard, you will have to write a custom script to achieve the purpose. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041676/1753098, to begin with.